# Strange bug when incrementing a value while iterating through a collection in Java

Tags: java, debugging, collections

I recently wrote a program that does Ant Colony Optimization on a graph.

The following code has a bug in it I can't understand.

```
    Map<Node, Edge> nodesLinkedToCurrentNode = a.getCurrentNode().getLinkedNodes();

    TreeMap<Double, Node> probabilitiesForNodes = new TreeMap<>();
    double totalProb = 0d;

    for (Node n : graph.values()) {
        if (!a.getVisited().contains(n)) {
            //For each node that has not yet been visited
            //calculate it's weighted probabily
            double weightedProbability
                    = (Math.pow(nodesLinkedToCurrentNode.get(n).getPheremoneLevel(), RPI))
                    * (Math.pow((double) 1 / nodesLinkedToCurrentNode.get(n).getDistance(), RHI));
            totalProb += weightedProbability;

            //Map the node to its probability
            probabilitiesForNodes.put(weightedProbability, n);
        }
    }

    double testTotalProb = 0d;
    for (Double d : probabilitiesForNodes.keySet()) {
        testTotalProb += d;
    }
    if (testTotalProb != totalProb) { <----------How can this happen??
        System.out.println("Why?");
        totalProb = testTotalProb;
    }
```

That if statement executes all the time and I don't understand why.

I'm just incrementing a value, but for some reason, it's not being incremented properly.

[I made the project open source, if you want to check it out](https://github.com/OliverFunk/tsp)

[The java file with the code in it](https://github.com/OliverFunk/tsp/blob/master/src/Graph.java)

I replicated the bug with the following code:

```
    TreeMap<Double, String> probabilitiesForNodes = new TreeMap<>();
    double totalProb = 0d;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        //For each node that has not yet been visited
        //calulate it's weighted probabily
        double weightedProbability
                = (Math.pow(0.7 + 1 / i, 2))
                * (Math.pow((double) 1 / 30, i));
        totalProb += weightedProbability;

        String sudoNode = "node" + i;

        //Map the node to its probability
        probabilitiesForNodes.put(weightedProbability, sudoNode);
    }

    double testTotalProb = 0d;
    for (Double d : probabilitiesForNodes.keySet()) {
        testTotalProb += d;
    }
    if (testTotalProb != totalProb) {
        System.out.println("Why?");
        totalProb = testTotalProb;
    }
```

Comment: Floating point numbers (`float`, `double`) have very limited precision. Consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `Double` in your code.

Comment: @MickMnemonic That really doesn't answer why it is happening. Analysis his code tells me, till now, that really that should not happen.

Comment: If the comparison and arithmetic of floating point numbers was 100% precise, then you're justified in being surprised that the condition evaluates to true. I think you have an age-old case of unprecise arithmetic/comparison here. I suggest you follow the advice of @MickMnemonic and use a BigDecimal instead.

Comment: @hagrawal, the OP is summing up a bunch of floats and assuming they equate exactly with some other float; I'd say it has everything to do with rounding errors.

Comment: But still OP is using same variable `weightedProbability` to increment `totalProb` and then putting it in `probabilitiesForNodes` which is incrementing `testTotalProb`. So, IF should not execute.

Comment: @hagrawal try this: `System.out.println( 1d / 100 / 100 / 100 / 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100);`, after that, try this: `System.out.println( 1d / 100 * 100 / 100 * 100 / 100 * 100 / 100 * 100);`. Still think that the order of operation does not matter?

Comment: @Turing85 I am not debating on floating point imprecision or order of operation, I know in 1991 gulf war 28 American solders has lost their life because of floating point imprecision, but like I said my approach is different on this problem.

Comment: In a nutshell, my point is: you should not compare results of float arithmetic with `==` / `!=`; such code is inherently broken.

Comment: Though this particular problem might have something to do with floating point arithmetics (real numbers sum is commutative, while floating point numbers sum isn't), maybe there's a simpler explanation... Maybe 2 or more nodes have the same weighted probability, so there would be only one node mapped to that probability (actually, the last one added).

Comment: Just curious... why are you mapping the nodes to their weighted probability, and why do you need such a structure?

Comment: Can you try after using `TreeSet<Double> probabilitiesForNodesSet = new TreeSet<>();` and then using `add` method to add the double values. You are using same `weightedProbability` variable value is each case, so should be OK. We will deal with your map requirement later, first lets debug the root cause, so for now try a Set collection.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the TreeMap isn't necessarily required, I just wanted a collection I could access the min/max value in constant time, as the max weightedProb is needed further down the method (check it out [here](https://github.com/OliverFunk/tsp/blob/master/src/Graph.java#L301)). Also, I just learnt about trees and maps etc. in my CS course, so I am was quite interested in them. Can you suggest a better way to to link a node to a number (i.e. a weight)?

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, I think has something to do with rounding/precision (see the updated question). Can you suggest a better way to do this then?

Comment: @oliver Good you're learning structures! I think you dont need a treemap. Use the PriorityQueue class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with `double` numbers so you should expect this. Specifically you obtain `totalProb` and `testTotalProb` by iteratively adding the same `double` numbers, but in different order. Since adding doubles is not an exactly associative operation, enough discrepancy occurs to make your equality test fail.

Another thing that can happen is a collision on the same `Double` key. There is nothing stopping two nodes from having exactly the same weighted probability. So for starters you can just check the sizes of the two collections.

Comment: To test this hypothesis, one could order the `keySet` before iterating through (in both cases). This should yield for both variables the same value.